# Adding magnetic dipoles and finding the field

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, magnetic-moment

If I have three magnetic dipoles and I want to model the field they produce together, how would I calculate that so I can model it in Mathematica? Assume the poles are permanent magnetic dipoles arranged so the poles can't move. For example:

[image]

Comment: Just for clarification, are you asking how to combine the fields from three dipoles (just vector add them) or are you asking how to write a Mathematica notebook to do this? The latter would be off-topic.

Comment: No, I'm interested in the formulization of this addition. I can combine the three dipoles and come up with an average dipole, but, I want to know the field of the dipoles. So, for example, what would the field be to the left of the figure and what would the field be to one unit length above the figure, etc... I'm looking to mathematically describe all space about this configuration.

Comment: At any point in space $\mathbf{r}$ the field from dipole 1 will be a vector $\mathbf{B}_1(\mathbf{r})$, the field from the second dipole will be a vector $\mathbf{B}_2(\mathbf{r})$ and the third dipole $\mathbf{B}_3(\mathbf{r})$. Just add up the three vectors to get the total field: $\mathbf{B} = \mathbf{B}_1 + \mathbf{B}_2 + \mathbf{B}_3$.

Comment: Ok, so that is very helpful - I guess the last thing I need to figure out is how to calculate B. Is Biot-Savart the only way to get there?

Comment: You could use Biot-Savart, [but I'd use Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_dipole)

Comment: So ... look at it on wikipedia isn't really helpful. I'm looking for something a bit more specific.

Comment: Maybe I can use the vector potential where:
$\nabla X \overset{\rightharpoonup }{A} =\overset{\rightharpoonup }{B}$

Comment: where the potential is: 
$\overset{\rightharpoonup }{A} (\overset{\rightharpoonup }{x})=\frac{\mu _o}{4 \pi }\frac{ \overset{\rightharpoonup }{m}~ x \overset{\rightharpoonup }{x}}{\left|\overset{\rightharpoonup }{x}|^3\right.}$ ?

Comment: Nevermind - I didn't realize your wikipedia comment was a link - it has all the same stuff I just posted. THANK YOU! 

I don't know if there is a way to mark your comment as the answer though?

Comment: Biot-Savart is not useful here, this is a point dipole not a finite size current filament.

Comment: I don't understand how this is off topic .... ?? I am curious about the Halbach array and specifically interested in building a model on how the dipoles create a field on one side of the array but not the other - and I was trying to avoid boundary conditions to do a first order approximation in the model. So how could this have been more appropriately asked elsewhere?